# does memcpy params have to be of the same type?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2008

I was reading that memcpy takes the number of bytes from a source location and adds it to a destination location. Does this mean that memcpy could possibly change datatype entirely ??

```
memcpy(DoubleOne, CharTwo, strlen(CharTwo));
```

considering that both values are empty still.

Comment: it doesn't "add" the bytes from the source location to the destination. It _copies_ the bytes... and, no, it doesn't care what data type those bytes actually correspond to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they dont have to.

```
int test = 3;
char dest[sizeof(int)];

memcpy(&dest[0], &test, sizeof(int));
```

Is valid c(++).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, `memcpy` doesn't care about the types. (It converts both its parameters to void pointers anyway)

It doesn't "change datatype" as much as it just writes `char` data into a `double` array (in your case) and hopes it makes sense.